# Using int 21h with inline assembly

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, assembly, inline-assembly

I am using inline assembly in Visual C++ and have been trying for days now to get int 21h to work with my program. Other interrupts work (int 3) which leads me to believe either I'm calling 21h wrong or it is blocked somehow. I only get a runtime error when I use int 21h. If I comment it out it can move registers fine.

So far I've gotten this together:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    __asm {
        mov ah, 1h
        int 21h

        mov dl, al
        mov ah, 2h
        int 21h
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of program is this? Int21h is a DOS interrupt.

Comment: Probably it's a segfault. You can't use ints in 32 bit apps as far as i know..

Comment: As stated, other interrupts do work. int 3 successfully makes breakpoints without error. The only one I seem to have trouble with is int 21h.

Comment: If you want a DOS program, use Turbo C++ or Open Watcom C/C++ or DJGPP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use DOS interrupts in a windows program; they are different platforms

You can use hardware interrupts such as `int 1` and `int 3`.

Comment: Been reading ever since I asked this and this seems to be the case. Thanks for the explanation on why int 3 works, makes more sense now.