# Accepts and displays one character of 1 through 9 using assembly code in c

Tags: inline-assembly

Can someone please explain me each line of this assembly code?

```
void main(void){
  _asm{
mov ah,8 ;read key no echo
int 21h
cmp al,‘0’ ;filter key code
jb big
cmp al,‘9’
ja big
mov dl,al ;echo 0 – 9
mov ah,2
int 21h
big:
}
}
```

PS: I am new to assembly in c/c++.

Comment: What OS/compiler is this code targeted at? The use of 16-bit assembly makes me think it's something very, very old.

Comment: The input is not in ah, it's in al (per [docs](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-8.html)).

Comment: `int 21h` is programming to the old DOS interface, while Visual C++ usually targets the Windows interface. Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/9524388/39223

Comment: @RJHunter  thanks for pointing the mistake...I am totally new to assembly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [docs](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-8.html), the return value is in `al`, not `ah`.  That's why it compares to al.

---

Edit: Adding more detail:

Looking at this code:

```
mov ah,8 ;read key no echo
int 21h
```

Think of this like a function call.  Now normally a function call in asm looks like `call myroutine`.  But DOS used interrupts to allow you to call various operating system functions (read a key from the keyboard, read data from a file, etc).

So, executing the `int 21h` instruction called the operating system.  But how was the operating system supposed to know *which* OS function you wanted?  Typically by putting a value in `ah`.  If you search, you can find a number of resources that show listings of all the `int 21h` functions (like [this](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21.html)).  The numbers on the right are the values you put in `ah`.

So, `mov ah,8` is preparing to call the "Wait for console input without echo" function.  `mov ah,2` is "Display output."  Other registers are used to pass various parameters to the function being called.  You need to read the description of the specific interrupt to understand what goes where.

Note that NONE of this is related to "writing inline asm in C."  This is just how to call OS function from C code running under DOS.  If you aren't running under DOS, `int 21` won't work.

Comment: Can you please explain the code and its working? It would be a great help for me since I am new to assembly in c

Comment: I will if you insist.  But this is a really bad way to learn asm.  Current operating systems (Windows, Linux, etc) don't use `int 21h` anymore.  So unless you are running DOS (or an emulator), it's not going to work.  Also, writing inline asm inside a C program is usually a bad idea.  If you want to write assembly, you write an assembly file (with a .asm or .s extension), then assemble and link it.  Google might be a better place to start.

Comment: I know how to write 8086 assembly codes .i.e. .asm files and but I am new to the  assembly language in c.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what your question is.  `cmp`, `jb`, `mov` are all basic 8086 instructions.  So is `int 21h`, but it only worked under DOS and DOS emulators.  You can see more of the syntax of using msvc's inline asm [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45yd4tzz.aspx), but you'd usually be better off writing asm in an asm file, then calling it from your C code.  Also note that msvc doesn't support using inline asm *at all* in 64bit code.